# How to make chromedriver open chrome open as a new user in python programatically

Tags: python, selenium, python-behave

I have a use case for my client where we want to perform test automation using Selenium in python and behave framework.

Now the client website is actually behind an Azure AD Authentication. So for example I am logged into a machine as user ABC, and I try to access the website it will log me in with that user. But if I want to login with another user id for ex: XYZ this will still login to ABC. To avoid this from happening we need to right click on chrome and say start chrome as another user. This will then give a popup for username and password with an attached domain.

So I want to ask is there any way we can do this programmatically using selenium web driver python code. I.e. is there any way to start chrome as another user programatically where I can specify the domain,username and password.

Comment: Have you tried using pyautogui and simulate the rightclick on google with mouse?

Comment: This will surely work but is not what i want to do because it involves another dependency other than selenium.

Comment: Yes you have the right i haven't found a way with selenium if i  find smt i'll send you.

Comment: not sure if this can help, but did you try to run them on docker? you can start a new session for every scenario from before_scenario on after_scenatio